# Slow query with order by join table

Tags: postgresql, index, index-tuning, postgresql-9.5

I have a SQL with multiple join left, because some data is empty.
However, I need to sort the data using a string column from a join table.

I thought about creating an index for this table, but this index does not affect this SQL.
How can I lower the cost of this SQL?

```
SELECT
*
FROM 
sales s 
LEFT JOIN salesman sm ON s.idsalesman = sm.id AND sm.account = s.account
WHERE s.situation = 2
AND s.account = 123
ORDER BY sm.name DESC
OFFSET 0 
LIMIT 30;

CREATE INDEX idx_salesman_name ON salesman (name  NULLS FIRST);
```

This is the Explain Analyze:

```
Limit  (cost=5228.94..5229.01 rows=30 width=2153) (actual time=7.435..7.459 rows=30 loops=1)
   ->  Sort  (cost=5228.94..5240.47 rows=4615 width=2153) (actual time=7.434..7.455 rows=30 loops=1)
         Sort Key: sm.name DESC
         Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 87kB
         ->  Hash Left Join  (cost=36.57..5092.64 rows=4615 width=2153) (actual time=0.992..6.634 rows=153 loops=1)
               Hash Cond: ((s.account = sm.account) AND (s.idsalesman = sm.id))
               ->  Index Scan using idx_sales_conta_situation on sales s  (cost=0.43..5021.83 rows=4615 width=1252) (actual time=0.096..5.489 rows=153 loops=1)
                     Index Cond: ((account = 123) AND (situation = 2))
               ->  Hash  (cost=35.33..35.33 rows=54 width=901) (actual time=0.811..0.811 rows=55 loops=1)
                     Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 30kB
                     ->  Index Scan using idx_salesman_account on salesman sm  (cost=0.29..35.33 rows=54 width=901) (actual time=0.052..0.748 rows=55 loops=1)
                           Index Cond: (account = 123)
 Planning time: 5.513 ms
 Execution time: 7.854 ms
(14 rows)
```

PostgreSQL Version: 9.5.14

Comment: `LIMIT 0`? Are you sure about that?

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ, my bad, I typed the values ​​in the wrong order of the example

Comment: How many rows in "sales" satisfy `s.situation = 2 AND s.account = 123`? This is a performance question.  Please see https://dba.stackexchange.com/tags/postgresql-performance/info

Comment: @jjanes About 1000 results, But there are about 350K rows in sales with different accounts and the `situation = 2`.
If I remove the order by the cost of SQL decreases from 40K to 169

Comment: Did you consider instructions at https://dba.stackexchange.com/tags/postgresql-performance/info like jjanes suggested?

Comment: Thanks @ErwinBrandstetter, I added the explain analyze result

Comment: less than 8ms seems quite fast. How fast do you need that to be?

Comment: The run time may vary depending on the situation or even if I change the value of the account.
There are several of these rows SQLs with different accounts, and the server CPU usage is between 95% and 100%.
Only PostgreSQL runs on this server.
The cost of SQL is high.

Comment: If sorting less than 5000 rows brings your server to its knees there is something wrong with your server. A cost value of 5229 doesn't really qualify as "high". The sort step from your plan takes about 1 millisecond. I doubt you can see a CPU spike of that duration on your server

Comment: Can it be a problem in the PostgreSQL configuration?

Ubuntu 16.04.1 x64
6 vCPUs
16GB / SSD Disk

I use pgBouncer to manage the connections.